# Python - Tkinter GUI update multiple modules

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

thanks in advance for any help.

I have 2 .py files, one which runs a GUI and another which does a basic calculation and creates a graph with the input of the GUI, these are then outputted to the console. The values are printed twice, once from the calculation file and again from the GUI file.

The problem is that if I update the input the output doesn't update and neither does the graph. Thank you in advance for any help with this.

**GUI (test1GUI.py):**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

import csv

def To_Print(self):

    if len(self.e_xf.get()) != 0:

        Write_Inputs_To_CSV(self)

        import test1Eqm

        test1Eqm.Pre_Output()

        Rmin = test1Eqm.Outputs('Rmin')
        xf = float(self.e_xf.get())/100

        print('xf (fromGUI) = ', xf)
        print('Rmin (fromGUI) = ', Rmin)

        del test1Eqm

    else:
        print('Enter All Inputs')

def Write_Inputs_To_CSV(self):

    xf = float(self.e_xf.get())/100


    with open('TestInputs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:

        filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                                quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

        filewriter.writerow(['Variable', 'Value'])

        filewriter.writerow(['xf', xf])


class ChemEngApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "ChemEng")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        ##### Making Labels #####

        self.l_Title = ttk.Label(self, text="Start Page")
        self.l_Title.grid(row=0, columnspan = 2)

        self.l_xf = ttk.Label(self, text="xA of Feed (%)")
        self.l_xf.grid(row=1, sticky="e", padx=5)

        ##### Making Entry Boxes #####

        self.e_xf = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.e_xf.grid(row=1, column=1)             

        self.b_Run = ttk.Button(self, text="Click to Run", command=lambda: RUN(self))
        self.b_Run.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan = 2)  

        def RUN(self):

            To_Print(self)

class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = ChemEngApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

**Calculations (test1Eqm.py):**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Getting variables from .csv 

import csv

Variables = []
Values = []

def getval(x):

    with open('TestInputs.csv', 'rt') as g:
        reader = csv.reader(g)

        # read file row by row
        rowNr = 0
        for row in reader:
            # Skip the header row.
            if rowNr >= 1:
                #g.seek(0) <-- makes it freeze on start up
                Variables.append(row[0])
                Values.append(row[1])

            # Increase the row number
            rowNr = rowNr + 1

    if x == 'xf':
        x = float(Values[0])

    return x

xf = getval('xf')
Rmin = xf*2.5           # Multiplies xf by 2.5

xl = np.linspace(0,1,2)
yl = [xf, Rmin]

def GUI_MT():
    plt.plot(xl, yl, label='Test')
    plt.xlabel('xA')
    plt.ylabel('yA')
    plt.xlim([0, 1])
    plt.ylim([0, Rmin*1.5])
    plt.legend()
    plt.savefig('TestMT.png')
    plt.show()

def Pre_Output():
    print(' ')
    print('New Run')
    GUI_MT()
    print('xf (fromEqm) = ', xf)
    print('Rmin (fromEqm) = ', Rmin)

def Outputs(x):

    a = Rmin

    if x == 'Rmin':
        x = a

    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Run GUI instead')    
    print('xf = ', xf)
    print('Rmin = ', Rmin)
```

Comment: You should avoid those global variables ``Values`` and ``Variables``. And you're always only accessing ``Values[0]`` - so if you execute that function again, you can never get a different result - you will only eat away more memory by appending to the list.

Comment: The calculation file access' the input values via a .csv file which I know is updating because it has when I open it so it does change those values

Comment: Also it goes back to row 0 so  it replaces the old values

Answer (score 2):

test1Eqm.py only reads the CSV file when it's originally imported.  Importing it again does not cause any code to be executed, you just get another reference to the existing module.  Basically, all of its code needs to be inside functions that you actually call when you want the calculation to be performed.

Also, using a CSV file to transfer data from one module to another within a single program is completely insane.  Pass the data as parameters!

Comment: Is there anyway by which I can un-import the module? Obviously using `del test1Eqm` isn't working. The reason for the .csv is so that I don't hvae to use `self.` when referring to the entry boxes, and it allows the values to be easily accessed easily for further evaluation

Comment: Yes, there is a way to un-import a module.  I'm not going to bother telling you what it is, because that is the worst possible solution to the problem.  If you're going to insist on importing the data from a CSV for completely bogus reasons, then simply put the code that does so into a function, and call that function after the import.

Comment: The final app is an education tool where the values can be exported to excel hence the .csv. Thank you for your help